# What do the different role icons backgrounds mean?

Tags: pokemon-masters

I've gathered a few strike-role trainers.  Some have smooth backgrounds and others are jagged.

[image: Jagged vs Rounded strikes]

Is there a functional difference between the two?  Do the other roles have variations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spiky vs. smooth edges denote a physical attacker vs. a special attacker.

Spiky edges denote a physical attacker with a focus on a high attack stat (especially effective against opponents with a lower defense stat), while smooth edges denote a character with a high special attack stat (especially effective against opponents with lower special defense).

As far as I'm aware, other roles don't have this split.